# If $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are relatively prime, then $G=HK$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm struggling to proof that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of  finite index of a group $G$ such that $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are relatively prime, then $G=HK$. I don't know why I can't answer it, because this question seems easy. I'm stuck maybe because I've studied so far just Lagrange's theorem and some of its consequences. But I think we don't need much more, because this is the material covered so far by the Hungerford's book.

I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena no, maybe it's my problem, I found the proposition 4.8 and 4.9 very unintuitive and a little bit out of context.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We have the following fact:

1. If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, then $[H:H\cap K]\leq [G:K]$. If $[G:K]$ is finite, then $[H:H\cap K]=[G:K]$ if and only if $G=KH$. This is proposition $4.8$ of chapter I in Hungerford's *Algebra*.

It is easy to prove that $[G:H][H:H\cap K]=[G:K][K:H\cap K]$, from this conclude that $[G:H]\mid [K:H\cap K]$; since $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are relatively prime, and combinig this with $(1)$ we get $[G:H]=[K:H\cap K]$, so...

Comment: But how to $G=KH$, you've only proved $G=KH$, remember $KH$ is not necessarily equal to $HK$, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Interchange the roles of $H$ and $K$. You're welcome.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Thank you again, I'm writing down the solution, seeing if everything's all right :)

Comment: it seems all right :)

Comment: @user42912 In general it is not true that $HK = KH$. But it is true that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ then, $HK = KH$ if and only if $HK$ is a subgroup of G.

So since CamiloArosemena has shown that $KH = G$ then in particular, $KH$ is a subgroup of $G$, so $KH = HK$

Comment: @rustyracketman yes, that's what I've been thinking

Comment: Is there any alternative solution without using the result $1$

Comment: @SupriyoHalder exactly my thoughts

Comment: Can I check the details for fact 1:
By second isomorphism theorem:  $H/(H \cap K) \cong HK/K \leq G/K$. Then $[H : H \cap K] = [G : K]$ iff $|HK|=|G|$, which means $HK=G$.

Answer (score 1):

Try proving that [$G$ : $H\cap K$] $=$ [$G$ : $H$][$G$ : $K$].

And then see how you can use the fact that $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$

Comment: $G$ was not supposed to be necessarily finite, and $HK$ is not necessarily a subgroup..

Comment: @Berci Just wondering,how can HK not be a subgroup when the question wants us to prove that G =HK which means HK is itself a group?

Answer (score 0):

If $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are coprime, $[G:H∩K]=[G:H][G:K]$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431028/given-h-k-finite-index-subgroups-of-g-prove-that-the-order-of-g-h-cap-k/4014827#4014827) for a proof)

Observe that a coset of $H\cap K$ is just an intersection of a left coset of $H$ and a left coset of $K$.

Thus, every intersection of cosets of $H$ and $K$ are non-empty and make a coset of $H∩K$. In particular,
$$xK∩H≠\emptyset $$ $∀x∈G$. So if $g\in G$, then there exists a $h\in H$ such that $gK=hK$

So for every there is an element of $H$ in every left coset of $K$. Hence
$$G=\bigcup_{g\in G} gK=\bigcup_{h\in H} hK=HK$$

**Notation**: $[G:H]$ is the index of subgroup $H$ in group $G$