# Let G be a finite group and let H and K be subgroups of G. Suppose [G:K] and [G:H] are relatively prime. Prove G=HK

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

So I am rather confused on where to start this proof so all I've got is

$[G:H \cap K]=[G:H][H:H \cap K]$

$[G:H \cap k]=[G:K][K:H \cap K]$

Thus that implies $[G:H][H:H \cap K]=[G:K][K:H \cap K]$

This is where I get stuck.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372979

Answer (score 2):

We have $m=[G:K]=|G|/|K|$ and $n=[G:H]=|G|/|H|$.  But also $\gcd(m,n)=1=\gcd(|G|/|K|,|G|/|H|)$.  Multiplying by $|H||K|$ throughout we get $|H||K|=\gcd(|G||H|,|G||K|)$.  So $|H||K|=|G|\gcd(|H|,|K|)\ge |G| |H\cap K|$.  We multiply y by $|G|$ on both sides and rearrange this  get $\frac{|G|}{|H\cap K|}\ge \frac{|G|}{|H|}\frac{|G|}{|K|}$, i.e. $[G:H\cap K]\ge [G:H][G:K]$.  The reverse inequality is a property of indices, so we have equality throughout and $G=HK$.