# Show $G=H_3H_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H_3$ and $H_5$ normal subgroups of $G$ of index $3$ and $5$ respectively. Prove that every element $g\in G$ can be written in the form $g=h_3h_5$, with $h_3\in H_3$ and $h_5\in H_5$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372979

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key facts:

- The product $HN=\{hn:h\in H,n\in N\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $H$ and/or $N$ is normal.
- Index is transitive; if $A\le B\le G$ then $[G:A]=[G:B][B:A]$ and $[G:B]\mid [G:A]$.

So $H_3H_5\le G$ is in fact a subgroup.

As both $H_3$ & $H_5$ are subgroups of $H_3H_5$, $[G:H_3H_5]$ must divide both $[G:H_3]$ & $[G:H_5]$...