# Showing that the order of an intersection of a subgroup is a prime number $q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $pqr$ with $p,q$, and, $r$ distinct primes.
If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ with $\left | H \right |=pq\textrm{  and }\left | K \right |=qr$, prove that $\left | H\cap K \right |=q$.

Clearly, $\left | H\cap K \right |=q$ or $\left | H\cap K \right |=1$.

[image]

I am unable to understand the part where the author claims $a_{i}b_{k}$=$a_{j}b_{l}$ Only If...
What is he trying to achieve?
How is it even verifiable that there exists some elements $a_{i},a_{j},b_{t},b_{l}$ such that an equality holds?

Any aid is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

He's assuming that $|H\cap K|=1$ then proving a contradiction. If $a_i=a_j$ and $b_k=b_l$ then of course the equality will hold, but given the assumption that will be the only case - hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: observe that $|G:H|=r$ and $|G:K|=p$, hence gcd$(|G:H|,|G:K|)=1$. This [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372979/if-gh-and-gk-are-relatively-prime-then-g-hk) $G=HK$. Hence $$|G|=pqr=\frac{|H| \cdot |K|}{|H \cap K|}=\frac{pq \cdot qr}{|H \cap K|}$$
and it follows that $|H \cap K|=q$.