# Sufficient condition for $G=HK$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

First of all I'm reposting this question as at the previous one I haven't got the   satisfactory answer. The problem is : If $G$ be a group and $H, K\le G$.  $\mid G:H\mid$ and $\mid G:K\mid$ are co-prime.Show that $G=HK$.

My attempt to to prove this : First considering a map $\phi :L_1\rightarrow L_2×L_3$ where $L_1, L_2$ and $L_3$ are left cosets of $H\cap K, H$ and $K$ respectively. Now ,just proving that this map is injective and will be surjective iff $G=HK$shows that $\mid G:H\cap K\mid=\mid G:H\mid \mid G:K\mid$. Now the result $lcm(\mid G:H\mid,\mid G:K\mid)\le \mid G:H\cap K\mid \le \mid G:H\mid \mid G:K\mid$ implies the required result.But my question is how to prove the required result without going through the mapping part.I have posted the result previously, but haven't got the satisfactory answer.Please help me to prove this.

Comment: I suppose it was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414323/prove-that-gcd-mid-gh-mid-mid-gk-mid-1-rightarrow-g-hk)? You should not repost old questions again. You could still ask at the original question.

Comment: Yes, but it's not gotten the right answer

Comment: I think the answers above will really help.

Comment: The mentioned answer gives the proof with help of another result that $(1)$ $G=HK$ *iff* $\mid H:H\cap K\mid=\mid H:K\mid $.Yes, it's a good method,I have also done with similar process that I mentined, but $G=HK$ is proved by first establishing the equality of $(1)$.That is if we have to prove the required result, we have to first prove the lemma$(1)$. But how to prove $G=HK$ without help of this lemma.You can think that this repost is asking for an alternative solution.